# Magento _afterSave method?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I am working with Magento and currently developing a module where in the model I am using Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract with the save action.
In the save action I saw that there is a method called `_afterSave()` and inside that method another call `$this->cleanModelCache();`

The last call goes down to `Zend_Cache_Backend_File` in `_clean()` method.

In that model I am saving some simple data with a product sku.

Why is Magento using `$this->cleanModelCache()`? Is it not loading the execution time since in `var/cache` there can be a lot of cached files with metadata?

Is it recommended or better to use that `_afterSave()` method or override it with own method and ignore the `cleanModelCache()` ?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish? There is most likely a much higher-level event within Magento that you can observe instead of getting that far down in the weeds.

Comment: For example in the `Mage_Customer_AccountController` we have the `createPostAction()` where saves a new account. On save, Magento goes on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` on save method and encounters the `$this->_afterSave()`. I am using the same method for saving ( extending the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` and saving data. But sometimes I thing that when Magento calls `Zend_Cache_Backend_File` with `_clean()` method stays a bit more time.

Comment: Okay, but what is the new features/functionality you are trying to achieve when you extend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::_afterSave()`? It doesn’t sound like it is related to customer accounts if you are extending `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract`.